# Is it possible to extend a line with plotly in R?

Tags: r, graph, r-plotly, trend

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70979770/how-to-draw-a-line-between-two-given-points-in-r-with-plotly/70980449) about drawing a line that connects two given points using `add_lines()` from `plotly`. That makes me think about some other visualization aspects I want to give to my graph: to connect two given points and extend the line across the whole x-axis.

This is my current database:

```
dput(sma)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1640808000, 1640822400, 1640836800, 
1640851200, 1640865600, 1640880000, 1640894400, 1640908800, 1640923200, 
1640937600, 1640952000, 1640966400, 1640980800, 1640995200, 1641009600, 
1641024000, 1641038400, 1641052800, 1641067200, 1641081600, 1641096000, 
1641110400, 1641124800, 1641139200, 1641153600, 1641168000, 1641182400, 
1641196800, 1641211200, 1641225600, 1641240000, 1641254400, 1641268800, 
1641283200, 1641297600, 1641312000, 1641326400, 1641340800, 1641355200, 
1641369600, 1641384000, 1641398400, 1641412800, 1641427200, 1641441600, 
1641456000, 1641470400, 1641484800, 1641499200, 1641513600, 1641528000, 
1641542400, 1641556800, 1641571200, 1641585600, 1641600000, 1641614400, 
1641628800, 1641643200, 1641657600, 1641672000, 1641686400, 1641700800, 
1641715200, 1641729600, 1641744000, 1641758400, 1641772800, 1641787200, 
1641801600, 1641816000, 1641830400, 1641844800, 1641859200, 1641873600, 
1641888000, 1641902400, 1641916800, 1641931200, 1641945600, 1641960000, 
1641974400, 1641988800, 1642003200, 1642017600, 1642032000, 1642046400, 
1642060800, 1642075200, 1642089600, 1642104000, 1642118400, 1642132800, 
1642147200, 1642161600, 1642176000, 1642190400, 1642204800, 1642219200, 
1642233600, 1642248000, 1642262400, 1642276800, 1642291200, 1642305600, 
1642320000, 1642334400, 1642348800, 1642363200, 1642377600, 1642392000, 
1642406400, 1642420800, 1642435200, 1642449600, 1642464000, 1642478400, 
1642492800, 1642507200, 1642521600, 1642536000, 1642550400, 1642564800, 
1642579200, 1642593600, 1642608000, 1642622400, 1642636800, 1642651200, 
1642665600, 1642680000, 1642694400, 1642708800, 1642723200, 1642737600, 
1642752000, 1642766400, 1642780800, 1642795200, 1642809600, 1642824000, 
1642838400, 1642852800, 1642867200, 1642881600, 1642896000, 1642910400, 
1642924800, 1642939200, 1642953600, 1642968000, 1642982400, 1642996800, 
1643011200, 1643025600, 1643040000, 1643054400, 1643068800, 1643083200, 
1643097600, 1643112000, 1643126400, 1643140800, 1643155200, 1643169600, 
1643184000, 1643198400, 1643212800, 1643227200, 1643241600, 1643256000, 
1643270400, 1643284800, 1643299200, 1643313600, 1643328000, 1643342400, 
1643356800, 1643371200, 1643385600, 1643400000, 1643414400, 1643428800, 
1643443200, 1643457600, 1643472000, 1643486400, 1643500800, 1643515200, 
1643529600, 1643544000, 1643558400, 1643572800, 1643587200, 1643601600, 
1643616000, 1643630400, 1643644800, 1643659200, 1643673600, 1643688000, 
1643702400, 1643716800, 1643731200, 1643745600, 1643760000, 1643774400, 
1643788800, 1643803200, 1643817600, 1643832000, 1643846400, 1643860800, 
1643875200, 1643889600, 1643904000, 1643918400, 1643932800, 1643947200, 
1643961600, 1643976000, 1643990400, 1644004800, 1644019200, 1644033600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), open = c(0.12428, 
0.12167, 0.11791, 0.12133, 0.124, 0.12245, 0.12375, 0.12392, 
0.12379, 0.12166, 0.1239, 0.12416, 0.11915, 0.12107, 0.12243, 
0.12321, 0.12216, 0.12488, 0.12839, 0.12815, 0.12759, 0.12704, 
0.12746, 0.12669, 0.12634, 0.12571, 0.12455, 0.12455, 0.12861, 
0.12556, 0.12244, 0.12281, 0.12175, 0.12213, 0.12338, 0.12431, 
0.12216, 0.1217, 0.12407, 0.12479, 0.12338, 0.12365, 0.11492, 
0.11013, 0.10664, 0.10831, 0.10642, 0.10901, 0.10986, 0.10979, 
0.10398, 0.1033, 0.104, 0.10127, 0.10275, 0.10207, 0.10357, 0.10443, 
0.10514, 0.10271, 0.09677, 0.10175, 0.10111, 0.10103, 0.10221, 
0.10152, 0.10517, 0.10355, 0.10461, 0.10576, 0.10419, 0.09702, 
0.09658, 0.09847, 0.10165, 0.10064, 0.0999, 0.10119, 0.10199, 
0.10152, 0.10233, 0.10215, 0.10273, 0.1059, 0.10571, 0.10564, 
0.10405, 0.10608, 0.10475, 0.10286, 0.10122, 0.10018, 0.10022, 
0.10127, 0.09859, 0.10011, 0.10054, 0.10066, 0.10147, 0.10333, 
0.10762, 0.11317, 0.11409, 0.11525, 0.11243, 0.11022, 0.10932, 
0.11007, 0.10968, 0.11175, 0.11387, 0.11404, 0.11295, 0.10842, 
0.10746, 0.10779, 0.11022, 0.11553, 0.11481, 0.11341, 0.1146, 
0.11565, 0.11529, 0.11192, 0.11229, 0.11194, 0.11081, 0.10661, 
0.10554, 0.10666, 0.10636, 0.10864, 0.10741, 0.09956, 0.09362, 
0.09521, 0.09495, 0.0936, 0.09223, 0.08409, 0.0828, 0.07273, 
0.07066, 0.07008, 0.0701, 0.072, 0.0711, 0.07424, 0.07467, 0.07324, 
0.07124, 0.07559, 0.07096, 0.06866, 0.06469, 0.06602, 0.06853, 
0.07014, 0.06903, 0.06895, 0.07152, 0.0715, 0.07204, 0.07213, 
0.07263, 0.07346, 0.07471, 0.07629, 0.0757, 0.07368, 0.07013, 
0.07135, 0.07329, 0.07601, 0.07396, 0.07423, 0.07524, 0.074, 
0.0731, 0.0754, 0.07527, 0.07648, 0.07666, 0.07782, 0.07804, 
0.07598, 0.07785, 0.07924, 0.07924, 0.0803, 0.07938, 0.07773, 
0.07475, 0.07529, 0.07172, 0.07102, 0.07118, 0.07292, 0.07386, 
0.07367, 0.07504, 0.07506, 0.07524, 0.0764, 0.07571, 0.07642, 
0.07676, 0.07632, 0.0777, 0.07355, 0.07462, 0.07218, 0.07176, 
0.07262, 0.07203, 0.07313, 0.0723, 0.07433, 0.075, 0.07626, 0.07713, 
0.07766, 0.07823, 0.07916, 0.08149), high = c(0.1249, 0.1219, 
0.1221, 0.12449, 0.12468, 0.12469, 0.125, 0.12459, 0.12419, 0.12509, 
0.1247, 0.12435, 0.12219, 0.12314, 0.12337, 0.12379, 0.1257, 
0.13202, 0.12864, 0.12884, 0.12778, 0.12824, 0.1275, 0.12846, 
0.12643, 0.12586, 0.12611, 0.1293, 0.1291, 0.12598, 0.12539, 
0.12323, 0.12241, 0.1235, 0.1258, 0.12597, 0.1243, 0.12522, 0.12494, 
0.12527, 0.1252, 0.12372, 0.11609, 0.11294, 0.10881, 0.10838, 
0.11043, 0.11073, 0.1107, 0.11156, 0.1046, 0.10593, 0.10532, 
0.10439, 0.10434, 0.10447, 0.10498, 0.10556, 0.10518, 0.1035, 
0.10294, 0.10226, 0.10237, 0.10302, 0.10435, 0.10577, 0.10697, 
0.10637, 0.10794, 0.10592, 0.10451, 0.10002, 0.09904, 0.10209, 
0.10208, 0.10162, 0.10222, 0.10529, 0.10228, 0.10552, 0.10301, 
0.10383, 0.10751, 0.10666, 0.10712, 0.10641, 0.10727, 0.10798, 
0.10733, 0.10371, 0.10179, 0.10146, 0.10257, 0.10128, 0.10085, 
0.10155, 0.10168, 0.10219, 0.1042, 0.1084, 0.11577, 0.115, 0.11817, 
0.116, 0.1129, 0.11084, 0.11083, 0.1113, 0.11353, 0.11784, 0.11776, 
0.11845, 0.11295, 0.10911, 0.10845, 0.11478, 0.11579, 0.1175, 
0.11665, 0.11785, 0.11698, 0.1194, 0.11767, 0.11323, 0.11335, 
0.11267, 0.11098, 0.10751, 0.10698, 0.10684, 0.10928, 0.1089, 
0.10764, 0.10056, 0.09559, 0.09648, 0.09531, 0.0943, 0.09277, 
0.08542, 0.08315, 0.07432, 0.07523, 0.07335, 0.07358, 0.07323, 
0.07433, 0.07611, 0.07517, 0.07387, 0.07573, 0.07559, 0.0712, 
0.0701, 0.0662, 0.06954, 0.07125, 0.07021, 0.06932, 0.07309, 
0.073, 0.0732, 0.07273, 0.07317, 0.074, 0.07531, 0.07681, 0.07934, 
0.0757, 0.07448, 0.07179, 0.07405, 0.07721, 0.0763, 0.07491, 
0.07546, 0.07561, 0.07502, 0.07573, 0.07638, 0.0769, 0.07732, 
0.078, 0.07849, 0.07858, 0.07817, 0.07933, 0.08047, 0.08092, 
0.0805, 0.07974, 0.07813, 0.0763, 0.07558, 0.07249, 0.07182, 
0.07319, 0.0752, 0.07437, 0.07518, 0.07607, 0.07724, 0.07668, 
0.07748, 0.07744, 0.07743, 0.07725, 0.07776, 0.07836, 0.07492, 
0.07462, 0.07259, 0.07278, 0.07301, 0.07326, 0.0739, 0.07444, 
0.07535, 0.07669, 0.07729, 0.07824, 0.07928, 0.07934, 0.08162, 
0.08316), low = c(0.11978, 0.1178, 0.1172, 0.1201, 0.12178, 0.12205, 
0.12212, 0.12193, 0.12048, 0.12058, 0.12257, 0.11896, 0.11811, 
0.12107, 0.12117, 0.12129, 0.122, 0.12429, 0.1266, 0.12721, 0.1266, 
0.12661, 0.12412, 0.12504, 0.12548, 0.12404, 0.1243, 0.12431, 
0.12533, 0.12138, 0.12, 0.12036, 0.12059, 0.12162, 0.12222, 0.1203, 
0.12148, 0.12103, 0.12313, 0.12225, 0.12175, 0.11411, 0.10467, 
0.10653, 0.10525, 0.10507, 0.10529, 0.10833, 0.10878, 0.10316, 
0.10021, 0.10294, 0.09925, 0.10017, 0.1003, 0.10126, 0.10326, 
0.10373, 0.10133, 0.09563, 0.09632, 0.09935, 0.10089, 0.09973, 
0.10072, 0.10144, 0.10297, 0.10316, 0.10421, 0.10231, 0.09465, 
0.09572, 0.09618, 0.09773, 0.09974, 0.09863, 0.09931, 0.10089, 
0.10076, 0.10128, 0.10143, 0.10196, 0.10253, 0.10498, 0.1053, 
0.10303, 0.10376, 0.10452, 0.10154, 0.10024, 0.0996, 0.09903, 
0.1002, 0.09738, 0.09778, 0.09941, 0.1003, 0.10007, 0.10095, 
0.1027, 0.10753, 0.11202, 0.11312, 0.1108, 0.1097, 0.10787, 0.10805, 
0.10945, 0.10915, 0.10955, 0.11154, 0.11255, 0.10815, 0.10594, 
0.10556, 0.10715, 0.10988, 0.11185, 0.11061, 0.11198, 0.11243, 
0.11368, 0.11125, 0.10968, 0.11047, 0.11069, 0.10627, 0.10495, 
0.10497, 0.10559, 0.10482, 0.10695, 0.099, 0.09241, 0.09346, 
0.09452, 0.08974, 0.09206, 0.08209, 0.08185, 0.07179, 0.06451, 
0.06982, 0.06912, 0.06969, 0.06978, 0.07074, 0.07367, 0.07129, 
0.07085, 0.071, 0.07051, 0.06847, 0.06405, 0.06267, 0.0644, 0.06819, 
0.06828, 0.06762, 0.06881, 0.07029, 0.07149, 0.07066, 0.07069, 
0.07232, 0.07344, 0.07382, 0.07435, 0.07163, 0.0697, 0.0698, 
0.07053, 0.07294, 0.07338, 0.07073, 0.07214, 0.07394, 0.07241, 
0.07208, 0.07436, 0.0751, 0.0757, 0.07623, 0.07703, 0.07535, 
0.07524, 0.0776, 0.07782, 0.07924, 0.0789, 0.07693, 0.07389, 
0.07411, 0.07132, 0.07025, 0.07026, 0.07008, 0.07264, 0.07324, 
0.07341, 0.07425, 0.07435, 0.07507, 0.07561, 0.07569, 0.07585, 
0.07574, 0.07585, 0.07335, 0.0722, 0.07157, 0.071, 0.0716, 0.07029, 
0.07111, 0.07195, 0.07201, 0.07392, 0.07465, 0.07623, 0.07472, 
0.0775, 0.07763, 0.07878, 0.08125), close = c(0.12167, 0.11791, 
0.12137, 0.124, 0.12236, 0.12377, 0.12392, 0.12381, 0.12164, 
0.12389, 0.12415, 0.11915, 0.12109, 0.1224, 0.1232, 0.12214, 
0.12488, 0.12839, 0.1281, 0.12755, 0.12701, 0.12745, 0.12667, 
0.12633, 0.12575, 0.12454, 0.12458, 0.12859, 0.12555, 0.1224, 
0.12279, 0.12176, 0.12208, 0.12335, 0.12427, 0.12214, 0.1217, 
0.12403, 0.12473, 0.12335, 0.1237, 0.11486, 0.11016, 0.10653, 
0.10829, 0.10642, 0.10902, 0.10982, 0.10981, 0.10402, 0.10336, 
0.104, 0.10134, 0.10268, 0.10199, 0.10358, 0.10443, 0.10513, 
0.10274, 0.09678, 0.10175, 0.10115, 0.10107, 0.1022, 0.10152, 
0.10517, 0.10362, 0.10465, 0.10576, 0.10422, 0.09695, 0.09657, 
0.09841, 0.10165, 0.10065, 0.09993, 0.10115, 0.10199, 0.10155, 
0.10233, 0.10212, 0.10274, 0.10594, 0.10571, 0.10572, 0.10405, 
0.10609, 0.10478, 0.10286, 0.10132, 0.10018, 0.10025, 0.10122, 
0.09857, 0.10011, 0.10051, 0.10072, 0.10155, 0.10333, 0.10762, 
0.11307, 0.11414, 0.11527, 0.11241, 0.11021, 0.1093, 0.11005, 
0.10972, 0.11176, 0.11385, 0.11405, 0.1129, 0.10851, 0.10746, 
0.10777, 0.11022, 0.11558, 0.11485, 0.11349, 0.11465, 0.11569, 
0.11527, 0.1119, 0.11233, 0.11197, 0.11084, 0.10661, 0.10556, 
0.10664, 0.1064, 0.10863, 0.10743, 0.09959, 0.09358, 0.09525, 
0.09484, 0.09361, 0.09215, 0.08424, 0.08281, 0.0727, 0.0706, 
0.07001, 0.07005, 0.07199, 0.07117, 0.07421, 0.07469, 0.07327, 
0.07132, 0.07559, 0.07097, 0.06862, 0.0647, 0.066, 0.06857, 0.07012, 
0.06901, 0.06896, 0.0715, 0.07156, 0.07209, 0.07207, 0.07261, 
0.07345, 0.07469, 0.07625, 0.0758, 0.07376, 0.07006, 0.07137, 
0.07336, 0.07602, 0.07389, 0.07429, 0.0752, 0.07399, 0.07305, 
0.07533, 0.07525, 0.0765, 0.07666, 0.07782, 0.07804, 0.07596, 
0.07783, 0.07925, 0.07921, 0.08028, 0.07938, 0.0779, 0.07477, 
0.07534, 0.07174, 0.07103, 0.07122, 0.07289, 0.07387, 0.07369, 
0.07503, 0.07509, 0.07524, 0.07636, 0.07573, 0.07639, 0.07679, 
0.07628, 0.0777, 0.07359, 0.07462, 0.07216, 0.07173, 0.07265, 
0.07201, 0.07315, 0.07227, 0.07429, 0.07499, 0.07626, 0.07713, 
0.07766, 0.07819, 0.07915, 0.08148, 0.08275), volume = c(17894295, 
25956559, 19646834, 21073444, 18817421, 12316289, 11348380, 14945318, 
20611382, 29389056, 15639183, 23990903, 10230550, 11791876, 8849962, 
8712513, 17411436, 52294930, 13741243, 12159456, 10156693, 7392933, 
24556017, 12498171, 6585602, 9053311, 10389994, 32763165, 18691599, 
20920341, 17194082, 13384844, 10762647, 11238837, 20643490, 17826487, 
8605881, 12725146, 8033532, 14576577, 18203767, 33106274, 57475480, 
35090353, 19236551, 22848525, 19670114, 12209910, 9189784, 28139942, 
32849205, 23256020, 31210609, 23094329, 12240627, 12774399, 8347728, 
10614794, 13157648, 47509634, 20708007, 13009872, 5347605, 10099313, 
18566517, 24284140, 16257416, 13504669, 26353561, 13722621, 42173001, 
23675661, 8144656, 17929342, 9387011, 13854189, 14603858, 31616737, 
6704224, 24196867, 13695017, 11613987, 27856536, 13454585, 10497017, 
16458068, 16297639, 12785798, 19360445, 12732714, 10444114, 16201247, 
9645137, 19007416, 14556473, 9980469, 8106055, 13820499, 10194965, 
64253247, 161980227, 55008265, 62794334, 47634737, 27375292, 
28948205, 23303586, 15667935, 20378324, 42039932, 45234586, 55979026, 
38458874, 19968558, 11843244, 33406862, 42373158, 54126294, 46806385, 
61654732, 27197944, 59155494, 33707242, 23832047, 19967177, 10957640, 
15637922, 19658790, 13028772, 9082828, 24976755, 10789730, 39076951, 
49842677, 16384967, 15601195, 29659625, 14836814, 53131858, 26904846, 
50215911, 80446251, 31711637, 27684325, 18295756, 30244578, 25000228, 
31701319, 20297596, 17620148, 16712144, 24532847, 20024178, 61355138, 
49383309, 34613954, 15938600, 14048986, 9165050, 33670464, 28771619, 
24220858, 11889148, 24206767, 16696844, 19341205, 30682562, 48411541, 
31624605, 19583695, 7736058, 14697691, 20371228, 21601985, 14667855, 
11662673, 8565838, 8950674, 15198713, 18115403, 13873815, 9454750, 
13116891, 11227183, 17723342, 11168569, 17650051, 16902150, 16042595, 
12631966, 17581570, 22259046, 16421002, 23295568, 15918092, 18004724, 
24079621, 23097753, 12800081, 12312440, 13131810, 19374725, 14036774, 
15552921, 12017393, 6465640, 6071254, 8288237, 23909383, 15594514, 
13318570, 9361610, 7166725, 9715764, 8906698, 8078021, 8742947, 
5312715, 8228518, 7468992, 21681712, 15425063, 9088154, 16051149, 
14306452), trades = c(11591L, 13904L, 8770L, 8976L, 8889L, 7218L, 
7956L, 10289L, 8338L, 15267L, 7974L, 11350L, 6627L, 8199L, 5462L, 
5711L, 9750L, 27559L, 7345L, 7275L, 4761L, 4086L, 11405L, 7343L, 
3511L, 5410L, 4619L, 14885L, 10363L, 11337L, 10040L, 7900L, 6029L, 
6823L, 9894L, 9795L, 5252L, 8359L, 4739L, 8325L, 10895L, 17994L, 
26704L, 16954L, 11073L, 11451L, 10072L, 6270L, 4694L, 13397L, 
14960L, 9414L, 14906L, 12126L, 6198L, 5929L, 4447L, 4968L, 6663L, 
19502L, 8574L, 6111L, 2793L, 4580L, 7616L, 11026L, 7975L, 6380L, 
10178L, 7006L, 18590L, 11151L, 4108L, 7542L, 4110L, 7336L, 7791L, 
14672L, 3764L, 12346L, 6006L, 6644L, 14171L, 6804L, 5282L, 7091L, 
6975L, 7109L, 9196L, 7046L, 5131L, 7664L, 5566L, 9995L, 8029L, 
4665L, 3391L, 5387L, 5661L, 21898L, 63727L, 23335L, 25023L, 22152L, 
11598L, 12217L, 10815L, 6903L, 10246L, 25837L, 21694L, 21720L, 
12474L, 8370L, 5376L, 15747L, 18057L, 20906L, 17232L, 25948L, 
11954L, 24800L, 12686L, 9503L, 8451L, 6271L, 8233L, 10329L, 6095L, 
5637L, 9733L, 6092L, 13746L, 19684L, 7050L, 6934L, 13457L, 7401L, 
17572L, 11348L, 18615L, 25756L, 10412L, 10349L, 6128L, 12691L, 
9583L, 10143L, 7123L, 7471L, 6147L, 10867L, 6986L, 14811L, 15151L, 
9144L, 4273L, 4538L, 3426L, 9159L, 9095L, 8463L, 4558L, 7123L, 
6183L, 6101L, 8886L, 16735L, 8368L, 6808L, 3165L, 5547L, 8119L, 
9066L, 6105L, 5640L, 4008L, 4116L, 4971L, 6974L, 4911L, 3472L, 
4044L, 4096L, 5997L, 4972L, 7099L, 7793L, 6059L, 4567L, 5282L, 
6897L, 6491L, 10157L, 6830L, 6899L, 8623L, 9719L, 4053L, 4742L, 
4628L, 7551L, 5978L, 7164L, 4851L, 3556L, 3060L, 3858L, 8498L, 
6731L, 5812L, 3765L, 2530L, 3805L, 3734L, 4060L, 3785L, 2778L, 
4578L, 4151L, 8128L, 7304L, 3698L, 7376L, 5582L), SMA_5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.121462, 0.121882, 0.123084, 0.123572, 0.1231, 0.123406, 
0.123482, 0.122528, 0.121984, 0.122136, 0.121998, 0.121596, 0.122742, 
0.124202, 0.125342, 0.126212, 0.127186, 0.1277, 0.127356, 0.127002, 
0.126642, 0.126148, 0.125574, 0.125958, 0.125802, 0.125132, 0.124782, 
0.124218, 0.122916, 0.122476, 0.12285, 0.12272, 0.122708, 0.123098, 
0.123374, 0.12319, 0.123502, 0.122134, 0.11936, 0.11572, 0.112708, 
0.109252, 0.108084, 0.108016, 0.108672, 0.107818, 0.107206, 0.106202, 
0.104506, 0.10308, 0.102674, 0.102718, 0.102804, 0.103562, 0.103574, 
0.102532, 0.102166, 0.10151, 0.100698, 0.10059, 0.101538, 0.102222, 
0.102716, 0.103432, 0.104144, 0.104684, 0.10304, 0.10163, 0.100382, 
0.09956, 0.098846, 0.099442, 0.100358, 0.101074, 0.101054, 0.10139, 
0.101828, 0.102146, 0.102936, 0.103768, 0.104446, 0.104832, 0.105502, 
0.10527, 0.1047, 0.10382, 0.103046, 0.101878, 0.101166, 0.100308, 
0.100066, 0.100132, 0.100226, 0.100292, 0.101244, 0.102746, 0.105258, 
0.107942, 0.110686, 0.112502, 0.11302, 0.112266, 0.111448, 0.110338, 
0.110208, 0.110936, 0.111886, 0.112456, 0.112214, 0.111354, 0.110138, 
0.109372, 0.109908, 0.111176, 0.112382, 0.113758, 0.114852, 0.11479, 
0.1142, 0.113968, 0.113432, 0.112462, 0.11073, 0.109462, 0.108324, 
0.10721, 0.106768, 0.106932, 0.105738, 0.103126, 0.100896, 0.098138, 
0.095374, 0.093886, 0.092018, 0.08953, 0.085102, 0.0805, 0.076072, 
0.073234, 0.07107, 0.070764, 0.071486, 0.072422, 0.073066, 0.072932, 
0.073816, 0.073168, 0.071954, 0.07024, 0.069176, 0.067772, 0.067602, 
0.06768, 0.068532, 0.069632, 0.07023, 0.070624, 0.071236, 0.071966, 
0.072356, 0.072982, 0.073814, 0.07456, 0.07479, 0.074112, 0.073448, 
0.07287, 0.072914, 0.07294, 0.073786, 0.074552, 0.074678, 0.074084, 
0.074372, 0.074564, 0.074824, 0.075358, 0.076312, 0.076854, 0.076996, 
0.077262, 0.07778, 0.078058, 0.078506, 0.07919, 0.079204, 0.078308, 
0.077534, 0.075826, 0.074156, 0.07282, 0.072444, 0.07215, 0.07254, 
0.07334, 0.074114, 0.074584, 0.075082, 0.07549, 0.075762, 0.076102, 
0.07631, 0.076578, 0.07615, 0.075796, 0.07487, 0.07396, 0.07295, 
0.072634, 0.07234, 0.072362, 0.072874, 0.073342, 0.074192, 0.074988, 
0.076066, 0.076846, 0.077678, 0.078722, 0.079846), SMA_10 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.122434, 0.122682, 0.122806, 
0.122778, 0.122618, 0.122702, 0.122539, 0.122635, 0.123093, 0.123739, 
0.124105, 0.124391, 0.125221, 0.125779, 0.126172, 0.126427, 0.126667, 
0.126637, 0.126657, 0.126402, 0.125887, 0.125465, 0.124896, 0.124437, 
0.124139, 0.123991, 0.123751, 0.123463, 0.123007, 0.122925, 0.12302, 
0.123111, 0.122421, 0.121229, 0.119547, 0.117949, 0.116377, 0.115109, 
0.113688, 0.112196, 0.110263, 0.108229, 0.107143, 0.106261, 0.105876, 
0.105246, 0.104962, 0.104503, 0.104034, 0.103327, 0.102603, 0.102442, 
0.102157, 0.10213, 0.102082, 0.102035, 0.102194, 0.102113, 0.102065, 
0.102367, 0.103111, 0.102631, 0.102173, 0.101907, 0.101852, 0.101765, 
0.101241, 0.100994, 0.100728, 0.100307, 0.100118, 0.100635, 0.101252, 
0.102005, 0.102411, 0.102918, 0.10333, 0.103824, 0.104103, 0.104234, 
0.104133, 0.103939, 0.10369, 0.103218, 0.102504, 0.101943, 0.101589, 
0.101052, 0.100729, 0.100776, 0.101406, 0.102695, 0.104084, 0.105489, 
0.106873, 0.107883, 0.108762, 0.109695, 0.110512, 0.111355, 0.111978, 
0.112076, 0.111952, 0.111276, 0.110781, 0.110537, 0.110629, 0.111182, 
0.111695, 0.111868, 0.111948, 0.112112, 0.112349, 0.112688, 0.113175, 
0.113595, 0.113657, 0.11276, 0.111831, 0.111146, 0.110321, 0.109615, 
0.108831, 0.1076, 0.105725, 0.104053, 0.102453, 0.101153, 0.099812, 
0.097572, 0.095213, 0.09162, 0.087937, 0.084979, 0.082626, 0.0803, 
0.077933, 0.075993, 0.074247, 0.07315, 0.072001, 0.07229, 0.072327, 
0.072188, 0.071653, 0.071054, 0.070794, 0.070385, 0.069817, 0.069386, 
0.069404, 0.069001, 0.069113, 0.069458, 0.070249, 0.070994, 0.071606, 
0.072219, 0.072898, 0.073378, 0.073234, 0.073215, 0.073342, 0.073737, 
0.073865, 0.073949, 0.074, 0.073774, 0.073499, 0.073656, 0.074175, 
0.074688, 0.075018, 0.075198, 0.075613, 0.07578, 0.076043, 0.076569, 
0.077185, 0.07768, 0.078093, 0.078233, 0.078044, 0.077796, 0.077166, 
0.076673, 0.076012, 0.075376, 0.074842, 0.074183, 0.073748, 0.073467, 
0.073514, 0.073616, 0.074015, 0.074551, 0.075108, 0.075447, 0.07583, 
0.07582, 0.075779, 0.075486, 0.075135, 0.074764, 0.074392, 0.074068, 
0.073616, 0.073417, 0.073146, 0.073413, 0.073664, 0.074214, 0.07486, 
0.07551, 0.076457, 0.077417), SMA_20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.1232695, 
0.1235365, 0.1240135, 0.1242785, 0.124395, 0.1245645, 0.124603, 
0.124636, 0.124875, 0.1250705, 0.124996, 0.124928, 0.1250585, 
0.125108, 0.1251555, 0.125209, 0.125209, 0.12505, 0.124832, 0.1246635, 
0.1244535, 0.124288, 0.1236585, 0.122833, 0.121843, 0.12097, 
0.120064, 0.119286, 0.1183475, 0.1175605, 0.1166415, 0.11567, 
0.114782, 0.113745, 0.1127115, 0.1115975, 0.1106695, 0.109806, 
0.108861, 0.1077615, 0.106433, 0.1053355, 0.10465, 0.1041955, 
0.103979, 0.1036405, 0.103578, 0.103308, 0.1030495, 0.102847, 
0.102857, 0.1025365, 0.102165, 0.1020185, 0.101967, 0.1019, 0.1017175, 
0.1015535, 0.1013965, 0.101337, 0.1016145, 0.101633, 0.1017125, 
0.101956, 0.1021315, 0.1023415, 0.1022855, 0.102409, 0.1024155, 
0.1022705, 0.1021255, 0.102287, 0.102471, 0.1026115, 0.1024575, 
0.1024305, 0.1024595, 0.102438, 0.102416, 0.102505, 0.1027695, 
0.103317, 0.103887, 0.1043535, 0.1046885, 0.104913, 0.1051755, 
0.1053735, 0.1056205, 0.1060655, 0.106692, 0.1073855, 0.108018, 
0.1083825, 0.108827, 0.10921, 0.1096955, 0.1104385, 0.1111035, 
0.1116115, 0.111963, 0.112094, 0.1121505, 0.111982, 0.111978, 
0.112066, 0.112143, 0.111971, 0.111763, 0.111507, 0.1111345, 
0.1108635, 0.11059, 0.110144, 0.10945, 0.108824, 0.108055, 0.1069565, 
0.1058215, 0.104359, 0.102767, 0.1006175, 0.0983839999999999, 
0.0962894999999999, 0.0941754999999999, 0.0921764999999999, 0.0901929999999999, 
0.0885729999999999, 0.0870294999999999, 0.0853609999999999, 0.0836069999999999, 
0.0819549999999999, 0.0801319999999999, 0.0785834999999999, 0.0771394999999999, 
0.0756769999999999, 0.0743634999999999, 0.0731889999999999, 0.0720319999999999, 
0.0712679999999999, 0.0707024999999999, 0.0706454999999999, 0.0707199999999999, 
0.0708229999999999, 0.0709509999999999, 0.0710239999999999, 0.0711999999999999, 
0.0713019999999999, 0.0713574999999999, 0.0713819999999999, 0.0713189999999999, 
0.0711079999999999, 0.0712274999999999, 0.0715974999999999, 0.0720569999999999, 
0.0724714999999999, 0.0728029999999999, 0.0729964999999999, 0.0731984999999999, 
0.0735169999999999, 0.0737044999999999, 0.0739514999999999, 0.0741799999999999, 
0.0744674999999999, 0.0747389999999999, 0.0748644999999999, 0.0750214999999999, 
0.0751714999999999, 0.0753419999999999, 0.0756679999999999, 0.0761339999999999, 
0.0764604999999999, 0.0765309999999999, 0.0764969999999999, 0.0763894999999999, 
0.0762264999999999, 0.0760274999999999, 0.0759724999999999, 0.0760134999999999, 
0.0759314999999999, 0.0759204999999999, 0.0758499999999999, 0.0757789999999999, 
0.0757059999999999, 0.0755904999999999, 0.0756119999999999, 0.0755599999999999, 
0.0754114999999999, 0.0753359999999999, 0.0750014999999999, 0.0747634999999999, 
0.0744764999999999, 0.0743244999999999, 0.0741899999999999, 0.0742034999999999, 
0.0743094999999999, 0.0743619999999999, 0.0744319999999999, 0.0744879999999999, 
0.0746164999999999, 0.0747214999999999, 0.0748499999999999, 0.0749974999999999, 
0.0751369999999999, 0.0754244999999999, 0.0757424999999999)), row.names = c(NA, 
-225L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000105f1ef0>)
```

What I want is to connect the two highest highs and expand the line across all the x-axis. Here's the code to get that data:

```
highs <- arrange(sma, desc(high))%>%
    slice(1:2)
highs


                 time    open    high     low   close   volume trades    SMA_5   SMA_10   SMA_20
1: 2022-01-01 10:00:00 0.12488 0.13202 0.12429 0.12839 52294930  27559 0.124202 0.123093       NA
2: 2022-01-03 02:00:00 0.12455 0.12930 0.12431 0.12859 32763165  14885 0.125958 0.126657 0.124875
```

So basically I have 0.13202 from January 1st and 0.12930 from January 3rd as my highest highs. With some code such as:

```
add_lines(inherit = F, data = highs, x = ~time, y = ~high, 
name = "Higher highs trendline", line = list(color = "seagreen", width = 2.5, dash = "dot"))
```

I can draw the line exactly for the two points in my highs object. But what I want is that this line goes across all my graph. In short, given two points I want to draw a trendline the same way we used to do on basic algebra. Main code for my graph is:

```
sma %>% plot_ly(x = ~time, type="candlestick",
                       open = ~open, close = ~close,
                       high = ~high, low = ~low) %>%
    add_lines(x = ~time, y= ~SMA_5,  line = list(color = "gold", width = 2), inherit = F,
                name = "SMA 5", showlegend=T)%>%
    add_lines(x = ~time, y= ~SMA_10,  line = list(color = "deeppink", width = 2), inherit = F,
                name = "SMA 10", showlegend=T)%>%
    add_lines(x = ~time, y= ~SMA_20,  line = list(color = "purple", width = 2), inherit = F,
                name = "SMA 20", showlegend=T)%>%
    plotly::layout(title = paste0(nombre, " Simple Moving Average, ", tiempo),
        xaxis= list(title="Time", rangeslider = list(visible = F)), yaxis = list(title = "Price"),
        sliders=list(visible=F)) -> sma_
```

Any help and orientation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fit a linear model on the two high points, and predict it's values on the remaining dataset:

```
fit <- lm(high ~ time, data = highs)

sma %>% plot_ly(x = ~time, type="candlestick",
                open = ~open, close = ~close,
                high = ~high, low = ~low) %>%
  add_lines( x = ~time, y = ~predict(fit,sma))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked so smooth. Thanks!